# How to add serializer for fields only and not for the class itself

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2, jackson-dataformat-csv

I have a base JPA entity called `AbstractEntity` with property `code` and I also have a ton of other JPA entities (`ProductEntity`, `CategoryEntity`, `UserEntity`, etc), each of which extend from `AbstractEntity`.

Now some of the entities have references to other entities, for example `CategoryEntity` has an attribute called `parentCategory` or `ProductEntity` has a Collection of categories (`categories`).

Now I want with jackson to serialize a `ProductEntity`, but whenever an attribute is of type `AbstractEntity` I want it to print only the `code` and nothing else.

My solution was to add a custom `Serializer` for `AbstractEntity`, but as you may guess the `ProductEntity` is also an `AbstractEntity` so whenever I say `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(product)` I get just the `code`. And instead what I want is:

```
{
 code: 'abc',
 category : 'categoryA',
 price : '12 $',
 active : true
}
```

Is there a way to tell jackson to use my custom serializer only for the fields and not for the object itself? 
BTW I can't really use annotations as I don't have access to the code and like I said the classes are really a lot.

Comment: I believe you will find what you want [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance)

Comment: Hi Eduardo, and thank you for your response.. I read the article but I still don't understand how to solve my problem :(